# How do chat flags and suspensions work?

Tags: support, chat

I got suspended for posting a quote from a previously linked page which *taken out of context* would be viewed as extremely antagonistic and offensive.  (I actually removed the post a few seconds before being locked out.)  Who is doing the reviewing of the flags, how many people does it take, and how are suspensions meted out?  Is there any 'warning', or is it 30 minutes for any flag?  Does it increase?

How easy is it for someone to flag for kicks and another/others approve it for the lulz?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-many-chat-flags-are-required-to-remove-a-message-ban-a-user/100439#100439 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86479/how-do-chat-suspensions-work/100498#100498

Comment: @balpha Specifically, who actually sees the flag?  People not even in the room?

Comment: @NickT 10k users (total reputation on all Stack Exchange sites) get notified of flags in chat. And yes, this does apply to people who aren't specifically in the room that the flagged message is in.

Comment: @Kevin, and they're presented with no context I assume, just the one-line?

Comment: Pretty much. I mean, you can find the post and see the context yourself, but the flag itself is the just post. (Actually, I think there's a permalink to the post in the flag, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: @KevinY There is a permalink to the post, yeah.

Answer (score 5):

> Who is doing the reviewing of the flags

Users with > 10k reputation. [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86479/how-do-chat-suspensions-work/100498#100498)

> how many people does it take

At least 6 (or a moderator). [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-many-chat-flags-are-required-to-remove-a-message-ban-a-user/100439#100439)

> how are suspensions meted out

I have no idea what your question is

> Is there any 'warning', or is it 30 minutes for any flag

Neither. It's 30 minutes for having a message deleted as spam/offensive. [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-many-chat-flags-are-required-to-remove-a-message-ban-a-user/100439#100439)

> Does it increase?

No. It stacks up (i.e. 6 offensive messages deleted in close succession => 3 hours of suspension), but it doesn't increase.

> How easy is it for someone to flag for kicks and another/others approve it for the lulz?

I'll assume that's a rhetorical question.

Comment: [mete](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mete)

Comment: Are you sure about the value never increasing? We have reports of users who are getting hour-long suspensions for singular flags - one particular user seems to *always* get a full hour. There's no secondary messages to get flagged, so we're not sure where the extra time comes from.